# cknife version issues with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, knife

I'm running a command: `cknife cluster launch mysite-production app --bootstrap`

```
/Users/shamoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- cluster_chef/knife (LoadError)
    from /Users/shamoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/shamoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@mysite/gems/cluster_chef-0.1.0.x2/bin/cknife:4
    from /Users/shamoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@mysite/bin/cknife:19:in `load'
    from /Users/shamoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@mysite/bin/cknife:19
```

That's the error that I get. I've tried: `bundle install`, and that shows: `Your bundle is complete! Use`bundle show [gemname]`to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

So what's the deal with `cknife` that it's not installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried bundle execing the command?

So:

```
bundle exec cknife cluster launch mysite-production app --bootstrap
```

Comment: No problem! I've lost count of the number of times forgetting to bundle exec stuff has caused me really confusing bugs..

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to try to retrieve it from Rubygems but it's not there.

Did you run `gem install knife-cluster` at all and then run `bundle`?

And why do you use `cknife`?

https://github.com/rberger/knife-cluster

Comment: No clue... I inherited this project... what is cknife?

Comment: I think it's 'knife' rather than 'cknife'. Try to install the gem above as it is in my answer and then try to run it and see the results

Comment: I have no idea then, sorry.